# How to get array if value in array exists. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the `"id":"236"` exists in `spConfig['attributs'][125]['options']` get the array that is contained in.

How would you do this in jQuery ?

```
var spConfig = {
    "attributes": {
        "125": {
            "id": "125",
            "code": "pos_colours",
            "label": "Colour",
            "options": [{
                "id": "236",
                "label": "Dazzling Blue",
                "price": "0",
                "oldPrice": "0",
                "products": ["11148"]
            }, {
                "id": "305",
                "label": "Vintage Brown",
                "price": "0",
                "oldPrice": "0",
                "products": ["11786", "11787", "11788", "11789", "11790", "11791", "11792", "11793"]
            }]
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which array do you want to get, the `options` array? Or do you mean the object whose property "id" is 236?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is slightly complicated, but assuming `options.id`s are unique, you can use

```
function foo(arg) {
    var filtered;
    $.each(spConfig.attributes, function() {
        filtered = $(this.options).filter(function() {
            return this.id == arg;
        });
    });
    return (filtered.length) ? filtered[0].products : [];
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ppe9/6/)

The function to return an empty array when a nonexistent key is passed.

Also, if you have more than one `attribute` property (other than `125`) and want to iterate over them:

```
function foo(arg) {
    var filtered=[];
    $.each(spConfig.attributes, function() {
        filtered.push($(this.options).filter(function() {
            return this.id == arg;
        }));
    });
    filtered = $(filtered).filter(function() {
        return this.length;
    });
    return (filtered.length) ? filtered[0][0].products : [];
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ppe9/7/)

Or, if you'll always access the property `attribute[125]`, you may as well leave it hard-coded for simplicity:

```
function foo(arg) {
    var filtered = $(spConfig.attributes[125].options).filter(function() {
        return this.id == arg;
    });
    return (filtered.length) ? filtered[0].products : [];
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ppe9/8/)

Or passing the `attribute` property name if you need more customization.

```
function foo(arg, attr) {
    var filtered = $(spConfig.attributes[attr].options).filter(function() {
        return this.id == arg;
    });
    return (filtered.length) ? filtered[0].products : [];
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ppe9/9/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
if ($.inArray('yourmom', myArray) !== -1) ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply however the code that you have entered only returns whether or not yourmom is found in myArray it doesn't then tell me what key that contains the array yourmom is in... any ideas

Comment: This function is of no help for that task.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjHCH/)

```
function findMe(searchTerm, location) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < location.length; i++ ) {
        if(location[i]['id'] == searchTerm) {
            return location[i];        
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var searchTerm = '236';
var location = spConfig['attributes']['125']['options'];

var requiredObject = findMe( searchTerm, location );
​alert( requiredObject ? requiredObject['label'] : 'Not Found');​​​​​​
```

Comment: location is an array, not an object. Use the appropriate loop.

Comment: @bergi An array is an object, and it's contents are enumerable. Sure you can pick up prototype extensions, but that doesn't matter in this case since `['id'] == searchTerm` fails if it's null, and the prototype shouldn't be that cluttered anyway. Isn't this faster than a plain for loop anyway?

Comment: No, it is not faster. And yes, the prototype can have enumerable properties, e.g. when polyfilling es5 methods or `indexOf` for IE.

Comment: Yes you can enumerate the the prototype properties, but adding the `['id']` reference would return undefined anyway, which would fail the equality check and move on. And by cluttered I mean there wouldn't be enough extra properties to affect performance. If it's no faster though I suppose it makes no difference (updated it to regular).